# How to add an entire list contents into a Pyspark Dataframe row?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am creating a new pyspark dataframe from a list of strings. How should my code look like?

This is my list: ['there', 'is', 'one', 'that', 'commands'] and this is what I want ideally:

### words(header)

Row 1: ['there', 'is', 'one', 'that', 'commands']
Row 2: ['test', 'try'

I have tried out the following codes but none of them gave me exactly what I wanted.

```
test_list=['hi','bye','thanks']
test_list=sc.parallelize(test_list)

schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True)])
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(test_list, schema)
```

AND

```
test_list=['hi','bye','thanks']
test_list=sc.parallelize(test_list)
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(row(test_list), schema)
```

I cannot get the dataframes to show using df.show().

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to import [Row](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row) object, rest everything was fine.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import Row, StructType, StructField, StringType
test_list=['hi','bye','thanks']
test_list=sc.parallelize(test_list)

rdd= test_list.map(lambda t: Row(name=t))
schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
df.show()
+------+
|  name|
+------+
|    hi|
|   bye|
|thanks|
+------+
```

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing. Is this the same as...

NAME
['hi',''bye',thanks'] 

OR

NAME
'hi'
'bye'
'thanks'

Comment: Well, I thought that you are having problems in creating the DataFrame. Sorry, your Q is not clear to me then. If you coulc clarify, then I could make corresponding changes. Ho don't understand what you mean by this - "" NAME ['hi',''bye',thanks'] OR NAME 'hi' 'bye' 'thanks' ""

Comment: Hi cph, i wanted : NAME ['hi',''bye',thanks']. thank you!

Comment: So you want one column with entry NAME ‘hi’ ‘bye’ ‘thanks’? Can you please paste a picture of your dataset in your Question?

Comment: Hi there, I managed to troubleshoot my issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thats's great. All the best.